# How to build generic Lambda Expressions in C# for any Entity and any Property and Navigation

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, expression

I'd like somebody to help me building lambda expressions so as to become generic by reflection. I have the following function which returns the entity type by its name:

```
private Type GetEntityType(string EntityName)
{
    Assembly Data = Assembly.Load("Domain.Entities");
            Type type = Data.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Domain.Entities" && t.Name == EntityName)
            .ToList<Type>().First();
    return type;
}
```

So if I have some related entities for example Customers, Purchases and Items:

```
public partial class Customers
{

    public Customers()
    {
        this.Purchases = new HashSet<Purchases>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Purchases> Purchases { get; set; }
}

public partial class Purchases
{

    public Purchases()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Date DatePurchased { get; set; }

    public virtual Customers Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Items
{

    public Items()
    {
        this.Purchases = new HashSet<Purchases>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NameOfItem { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Purchases> Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

I can have expressions for Customers like:

```
c => c.Name
c => c.Name == "My name"
c => c.Name.Contains("My name")
```

For Purchases I could have:

```
p => p.Customers
p => p.Customers.Name
p => p.Customers.Name == "My Name"
p => p.Customers.Name.Contains("My Name")
```

I could also navigate from Customers to Items properties... but that would be a further step to me since I'd first need to transform those Expressions to generic so as to build them by any given Entity for which we know its name (returned by the function GtEntityType above) and any given property names and navigations like those in example.

Comment: I don't comprehend what you are trying to do. You showed us some code to get a type from a string (something that could have been done with `Assembly.Load(...).GetType("Domain.Entities" + EntityName)`, then you have showed us some entitites, then you have showed us some expressions... But I don't see what you want to do with those expressions. There is a missing link between the first two blocks of code and the last two blocks of code (the ones with the expressions)

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer from my side, I've been struggelling with these sort of topics. Please have a look to this question, there it is one of the aims I hava, so as to create p => p.Customers in the above example, alghouth I have used another example in the other link:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648810/create-expressionfunctentity-object-dynamically-and-call-aggregate-to-iquery

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I’m right what you want to do, but for example for lambda:

```
    Type t = this.GetEntityType("Customers");

    ParameterExpression parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(t);
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression property = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(parameter, "Purchases");
    LambdaExpression lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(property, parameter);
```

And later you can use it for example:

```
    MethodInfo selectQueryable = typeof(Queryable)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(method => method.Name == "Select")
                .Select(method => new { M = method, P = method.GetParameters() })
                .Where(x => x.P.Length == 2
                    && x.P[0].ParameterType.IsGenericType
                    && x.P[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>)
                    && x.P[1].ParameterType.IsGenericType
                    && x.P[1].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>))
                .Select(x => new { x.M, A = x.P[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments() })
                .Where(x => x.A.Length == 1
                    && x.A[0].IsGenericType
                    && x.A[0].GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>))
                .Select(x => x.M)
                .Single()
                .MakeGenericMethod(t,typeof(Purchases));


    var s = selectQueryable.Invoke(null, new[] { dbSet, lambda });
```

Comment: Sorry for giving you thanks so late. I think I can try that, but that would be some later. Now I'm trying to create dynamic lamda for Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> so that I can call Aggregate to Queryable... You may like to see this specific question I've just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648810/create-expressionfunctentity-object-dynamically-and-call-aggregate-to-iquery