# Create Expression<Func<TEntity,object>> dynamically and call Aggregate to IQueryable<TEntity>

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, delegates, expression

I'd like to create an `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` so as to later pass it to function as parameter.

If I use the following function for creating it...

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetInclude(string property)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ppty = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(parameter, property);
    LambdaExpression lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(ppty, parameter);

    return (Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>)lambda;
}
```

... I get the error at runtime trying to return result, saying that the type cannot be converted into object. For example, if `TEntity` is `Purchases` and I want to get `Purchases.Customers` by giving `"Customers"` as the parameter.

On the other hand, If I do that function to become generic like...

```
public Expression<Func<TEntity, TDest>> GetInclude<TDest>(string property) where TDest: class, new()
{
        ParameterExpression parameter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression ppty = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(parameter, property);
        LambdaExpression lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(ppty, parameter);

        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, TDest>>)lambda;
}
```

... and calling it from Generic Method...

```
MethodInfo methodInfoInclude = EntityRepository.GetMethod("GetInclude");
object[] parametersToIncludeArray = new object[] { "Customers" };  //For testing

//Get the type of object to be obtained:
Assembly Data = Assembly.Load("Domain.Entities");
Type EntityTypeReferenced = Data.GetTypes()
.Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == "Domain.Entities" && t.Name == "Customers") //For testing
.ToList<Type>().First();

MethodInfo methodInfoGenericInclude = methodInfoInclude.MakeGenericMethod(EntityTypeReferenced);
object include = methodInfoGenericInclude.Invoke(EntityRepositoryInstance, parametersToIncludeArray);
```

... I have no error and I can get the include object. However, when I call to method that requires `Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>` as a parameter:

```
        object[] Includes = { include };

        MethodInfo methodInfo = EntityRepository.GetMethod("GetElementsWithInclude");
        object[] parametersToIncludeFunctionArray = new object[] { Includes };
        object Data = methodInfo.Invoke(EntityRepositoryInstance, parametersToIncludeFunctionArray);
```

... with something like...

```
public List<TEntity> GetElementsWithInclude(Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[] Includes)
{
    return this.ApplyIncludes(this._Context.CreateDbSet<TEntity>(), Includes).AsEnumerable<TEntity>().ToList();
}
```

... I get the the error like `object[]` cannot be converted into `Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[]`.

The aim is calling function to `ApplyIncludes` like this, having created the expressions dynamically:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyIncludes(IDbSet<TEntity> Entities, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] Includes)
{
    return Includes.Aggregate(Entities.AsQueryable<TEntity>(),
        (Entity, Include) => Entity.Include(
            ((MemberExpression)Include.Body).Member.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(TEntity)) ?
            ((MemberExpression)Include.Body).Member.Name :
            Include.Body.ToString().Replace(Include.Parameters[0].Name + ".", "").Replace("FirstOrDefault().", "")
            ));
}
```

Any help with this, please???

Thank you so much.

Comment: Source of that `Includes.Aggregate`?

Comment: Why on the earth are you building an `Expression` just to pass it to `IDbSet<>.Include`? You have some string property names... Pass them to the `IDbSet<>.Include(string)`

Comment: Good Point! I was using ApplyIncludes function for creating Expressions when types and names are known beforehand for specific database. The usage of this function would benefit finding errors at compile time when model changes. However you've opened my mind, and actually since I'm now querying dynnamically at runtime, I don't need to create such expressions since the names are know at runtime and matching the model. Therefore, thanks, I have run it as you said and it looks good. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, it also validate that the property to include actually exists.

```
public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> BuildIncludeExpression(string include)
{

    var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    var propertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty(include); 
    if (propertyInfo == null) 
        throw new Exception("Unknown property");

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, include);
    
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, object>>(property, parameter);
}
```